# What's the relationships between the relevant concepts involved? Why these facts are mutually compatible?

Tags: first-order-logic

Gӧdel proved that FOL is complete. The arithmetical theory Q is closed under first-order logical consequence, and yet Gӧdel's theorems establish that Q is incomplete. What's the relationships between the relevant concepts involved? Why these facts are mutually compatible?

Comment: The term "(in)complete" is unfortunately overloaded: when we say "FOL is complete" we're referring to a totally different notion than when we say "$\mathsf{Q}$ is not complete." There's no tension, only unfortunate terminology.

Comment: 'First order logic is complete' means that exactly those formulas are provable from a theory which hold on every model of the theory, while 'incompleteness' *of a theory* means that there is a formula which has two models for the theory, in one of them it holds but it does not in the other one.

Comment: This question has been asked several times on this site. Besides the instance linked above, here are some more: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329535/g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness-vs-incompleteness), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435963/dont-g%C3%B6dels-completeness-and-incompleteness-theorems-contradict-each-other), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568819/some-questions-about-g%C3%B6dels-theorems-of-completeness-and-incompleteness). If after perusing these there is still some point of interest, you should edit your question to focus on that specifically.

Comment: (That said, please don't take my closing this question as an indication that it's a bad question - it's a very good question. But it has been asked and answered multiple times before.)